# Crystal Report and MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, crystal-reports

How to use Crystal Report within WPF-MVVM framework : how to integerate report viewer with WPF view and bind it to View Model to pass the report source and other parameters through the view model.Is it possible to open multiple reports at the same time?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: using something like this,

add this reference  
`xmlns:report="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms"`

then use the reportviewer control inside WindowsFormsHost

  `<Grid>
                    <WindowsFormsHost>
                        <report:ReportViewer x:Name="_reportViewer"/>
                    </WindowsFormsHost>
                </Grid>
`

then you can use it as usually